# Print Sum of two numbers Haskell

Tags: haskell

How can I print the result of sum of two numbers?

```
 main:: IO()
 main = do putStrLn "Insert the first value: "  
        one <- getLine  
        putStrLn "Insert the second value: "  
        two <- getLine    
        putStrLn "The result is:"
    print (one+two)
```

This gives me an error:

```
  ERROR file:.\IO.hs:3 - Type error in application
  *** Expression     : putStrLn "The result is:" print (one + two)
  *** Term           : putStrLn
  *** Type           : String -> IO ()
  *** Does not match : a -> b -> c -> d
```

Comment: More constructively, use GHC. If you prefer to use an interpreter rather than a compiler, you can use the `runghc` program included with GHC.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Hugs is fine to use for code such as this. runghc isn't an interactive interpreter. ghci is, and is also fine to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess that your error is related to not using parens.

Also, since `getLine` produces a string, you'll need to convert it to the correct type. We can use `read` to get a number from it, although it's possible it will cause an error if the string cannot be parsed, so you might want to check it only contains numbers before reading.

```
print (read one + read two)
```

Depending on precedence, the variables may be parsed to belong as parameters for `print` instead of to `+`. By using parens, we ensure the variables are associated with `+` and only the result of that is for `print`.

Lastly, make sure the indentation is correct. The way you've pasted it here is not correct with the do-expression. The first putStrLn should be on the same indentation level as the rest - at least ghc complains about it.

Comment: @user1966757 updated. need to use `read` to convert into number :)

Comment: Thanks, it was a problem of identation too.:)

Comment: @AndrewC Yeah indeed they are unnecessary with read. It was earlier just a `print one + two` at which point it would have caused an error :)

Answer (score 10):

Try to use `readLn` instead of `getLine`.

`getLine` returns a `String` in the `IO` monad and `String`s cannot be added.

`readLn` has polymorphic return type, and the compiler infers that the return type is `Integer` (in the `IO` monad) so you can add them.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your code this way using the `read :: Read a => String -> a`

```
 main:: IO()
 main = do putStrLn "Insert the first value: "  
        one <- getLine  
        putStrLn "Insert the second value: "  
        two <- getLine    
        putStrLn "The result is:"
    print ((read one) + (read two))
```

Comment: Your statements after do have to line up and there are unnecessary brackets `print (read one + read two)`